# c++ : Deck not showing first card

Tags: c++, playing-cards

I am actually trying to create a bluff game of cards in c++. When I call the function showAllCards the card at the of the deck ( Ace of Hearts ) does not show on output, the only way to show it is to add both deck structures in main body.And when program runs (without top card), dev generates some warnings too. What am I doing wrong?
Also can you please refer some improvements/changes in program.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Strings.h>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct link{
    int data;
    link *link;
};

struct deck
    {
        string suit[32];
        string value[32];
    }card;

struct cardsDeck{
    string nxt[20];
    string suitlist[4] = {"hearts","spades","clubs","diamonds"};
    string vals[8] = {"ace","two","three","four","five","jack","queen","king"};

}cdeck;

class Game
{
    private: 
    link *first;
    public:
        Game();
        void check();
        void mask();
        void pass();
        void enterCard();
        void showAllCards();
        void shuffle(); 
        void rearrangeCards();  
};

Game::Game(){
    first=NULL;
}

void Game::rearrangeCards(){
    short int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    while(x < 32)
    {
        card.suit[x] = cdeck.suitlist[y];
        card.value[x] = cdeck.vals[z];
        ++x;
        ++z;
        if(x % 8 == 0)
        {
            ++y;    
        }
        if(z % 8 == 0)
        {
            z = 0;
        }
    }

}

void Game::showAllCards(){
    int x;
    while(x < 32)
    {

        if(card.suit[x]!=card.suit[x-1]){
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << card.value[x] << " of " << card.suit[x] << "\n";
        ++x;
    }
}

int main(){
    Game game;
    int op;
    game.rearrangeCards();
    cout<<"Welcome to Bluff Mashter 20/12/15::6:46\nEnter the Operation please:\n\n";
    cin>>op;
    while(op!=0){
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                game.showAllCards();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;

        }
    }

    return 1;   
}
```

and here are the warnings

```
20  63  E:\Projjects\mainbluuf.cpp  [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
21  78  E:\Projjects\mainbluuf.cpp  [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
20  63  E:\Projjects\mainbluuf.cpp  [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
21  78  E:\Projjects\mainbluuf.cpp  [Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Comment: Enable C++11 in your project.

Comment: The warning suggests you if you want to use `initializers` with non static members, you should use `c++11` standard, just add `-std=c++11` to your build parameters

Comment: In `showAllCards`,  what is the value of `x` in the first iteration?

Comment: I did initialized 0 to x but then it hangs.
@JohnZwinck Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your method is this:

```
void Game::showAllCards(){
    int x = 0;
    while(x < 32)
    {

        if(card.suit[x]!=card.suit[x-1]){
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << card.value[x] << " of " << card.suit[x] << "\n";
        ++x;
    }
}
```

in your first iteration you're doing this: `card.suit[0]!=card.suit[-1]` which is wrong.

```
void Game::showAllCards(){
    int x = 1;
    while(x < 32)
    {

        if(card.suit[x]!=card.suit[x-1]){
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << card.value[x] << " of " << card.suit[x] << "\n";
        ++x;
    }
}
```

I didn't test the code though, but I guess that fixes the issue.

Note: I set `x` to `1` that's the only change. Since you're new to C++ by default `uninitialized` variables can contain any unpredicted values which is stored in that memory address, so the good practice is to ***always*** initialize your variables.

**Update**:

Try this:

```
void Game::showAllCards(){
    for(x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
    {
        cout << card.value[x] << " of " << card.suit[x] << "\n";
    }
}
```

***Update 2***:

```
int main(){
    Game game;
    int op;
    game.rearrangeCards();
    cout<<"Welcome to Bluff Mashter 20/12/15::6:46\nEnter the Operation please:\n\n";

    cin >> op;
    while(op!=0){
        switch(op){
            case 1:
                game.showAllCards();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;

        }

        cin >> op;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

***Update 3:***

```
void Game::showAllCards(){
    string lastSuit = "";

    for(x = 0; x < 32; ++x)
    {
        if(lastSuit != card.suit[x])
            cout << "\n";

        cout << card.value[x] << " of " << card.suit[x] << "\n";
        lastSuit = card.suit[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: This also skips the first card. You want to initialize `x = 0` and check something like `if(x == 0 || ...)`

Comment: That's correct, logic has to be changed slightly as well.

Comment: Declaring x as 1 also puts program in an infinite loop.
@CompuChip declaring x as zero hangs the program.

Comment: Why infinite loop? you increase `x` in every iteration, right? so eventually `x` will be bigger than 32

Comment: Another thing, I didn't understand why do you need that if? I guess you can just remove it.

Comment: @Boynux that's exactly what should happen but it somehow gets into an infinite loop, I think I have to change the logic but I still can't get anywhere.
If condition was used so that there should be a blank line after every suite.

Comment: I updated the answer, please give it a try. You can actually use: `for (int x = 1; x < 32; ++x)` which is more appropriate.

Comment: I tried it a few times, with declaring x=0, x=1, getting values through parameters and using for loop, if x=0 the program hangs and if x=1 program goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Ok, another bug, the function with last edited version is fine, in your main function you need to get `op` **inside** while loop again. That's why you get infinite loop :) Just copy `cin >> op` end of loop too.

Comment: Well iit did worked fine but still didn't shows the first card, I think there is something wrong with structure of cards. In update 2, we could just call cin once in while loop and initialize 1 to op, it will look a little neat.

Comment: Ah, just set `x` to zero to show the first card, assuming that you removed `if` clause.

Comment: Done, shows the first card. But how could I leave a blank line now after every other suite?

Answer (score 0):

After some logical torture and tips from Boynux I figured out both prblems.

```
for(int j=0;j<32;j++){
        cout<<card.value[j] << " of " << card.suit[j]<<"\n";
        if(j==7 || j==15 || j==23 || j==31)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
```